# node js + mongodb + schedule notifications

Tags: node.js, notifications, schedule

I´m new in nodejs, I´m trying to develope a calendar application with nodejs and mondodb, where users can schedule events (appointments, alerts, etc). Events could repeat in time(every 8 hours, evety 3 months, ...) and I want to notify users before the event start.

Can anyone help with this? Is there any module to manage this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I use this Node.js module for scheduling tasks...

https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule